# Using a model method in a where statement with Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a method in a model that return a number from 0 to 4, for example:

```
$myTask->currentStatus() //return 3
```

It works but I need to use it in a where method like this:

```
Task::where(currentStatus, 3)->get();
```

Is this possible with Laravel?

Comment: How does currentStatus work ? Does it have a query to the db ?

Comment: @Rezrazi It check some properties of the "task" object, such as the creation date and the update date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to filter your resulting collection

```php
$tasks = Task::get();
$output = $tasks->filter(function(Task $entry){
                    return $entry->currentStatus == 3;
});
```